# remove "~" from file name

Tags: bash, rename

I have a limited bash shell on my NAS and a lot of files that contains the char `~` in the filename.
For example, I have a file in `2018/10/example~1.jpg` and I have to move and rename it to `allFiles/2018-10-example_1.jpg`.

I have to replace the `~` with `_`, and add the path with the `-` instead of `/` in the filename.

Could you please help me?

P.S. Only files with `.jpg`/`.png`/`.mov` extension

Comment: Since you say that you have "a limited `bash` shell", it would be good to know in what way it is limited.

Comment: it's a QNAP NAS, there's a shell with all base commands but I can't install more program.

Comment: Can you assess the files from a Unix (UNIX, BSD, Gnu/Linux, MacOSX) machine? or is only access via its built in shell?

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/$$/cmdline`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a QNAP, but I believe its shell is actually BusyBox.  This should work with both BusyBox and bash (although with bash, you'd also need find+cut+awk to be installed):

Assuming the year directories (ie "2018") and the "allFiles" directories are at the same level, and that level is your current working directory in your shell:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' | cut -c3- | awk '{ newname=$0; gsub(/~/, "_", newname); gsub(/\//, "-", newname); gsub(/^/, "allFiles/", newname); print "mv " $0 " " newname; }'
```

That will produce a set of commands to move all your .jpg files.  Review the commands to make sure they're reasonable first.  Then run them by tacking on "| sh" to the end of the above command.

Then replace '*.jpg' in the above with another file extension you wanted to process, and repeat.

Comment: I'd suspect  sed(1) is more likely to be available than awk(1).... and I'd write out a script for doing the renaming, to check and run later.

Comment: As I mentioned, I believe QNAP uses BusyBox, and BusyBox has both sed and awk builtin, in which case there's no issue.  But if it's really using bash, then sure.